# on reboot only: Failed to start detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes

Tags: graphics, intel

Minisforum u820 "nuc-like" minipc, USB-C powered (using the provided adapter), 512GB Kingston SSD and 2x8GB RAM.
No dedicated GPU. Intel i5-8259 with built in 655 graphics.

After installing Ubuntu Budgie 21.04 (with Secure Boot disabled in bios), I have an issue when I reboot the device: it doesn't boot any further and shows 2 errors:

1. Failed to start detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes
2. Failed to start Light Display Manager.

I do NOT have this issue when I choose shutdown instead of reboot, then power on the device with its power button.

How can I solve this? I disabled quick-boot already, no change.

Comment: Maybe bootoption `nogpumanager` can help.

Comment: Thanks, that did help, I rebooted twice now after adding it.    
  For reference:
  
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`  
change: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`  
to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nogpumanager"`  
save and exit: CTRL+O, CTRL+X  
update grub: `sudo update-grub`  
  
When finished, rebooted. Booted straight to Ubuntu.   
I tried another reboot, success. Will now try after disabling quick boot.